# How do I build a full-functional RESTful API using Java Spring security

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm building a REST API for an application which is completely depends on this API(means no frontend at all). So I found myself struggling in 2 points:

**1. How do I implement authentication/registration and perform actions where auth is requiered using REST?**

Well, I know that applications like Instagram have a special page where users can generate **access_token** and use Instagram API with no restrictions(where auth is required). But in my case all I can do is to create a REST request like this

```
?action=generateToken&userName=someName&password=somePassword
```

And if username and password are correct I suppose to get **access_token** as a response.
The same with registration here

```
?action=register&userName=someName&password=somePassword
```

And here I get greeting message and **access_token**

The question is how should I **store, generate, refresh, manipulate** in general with these tokens? Should I have a separate database, where token itself and related user(id) are stored? And of course I should delete these tokens after N minutes. For how long am I supposed to store a token? Otherwise anyone who somehow stole a token has access to all the user's functions. How can I do that?

If I got it right any action where user identification is required can be done like this

```
?action=sendMessage&access_token=someToken&recipientId=100&message=TestAuthOut!
```

where **access_token** is a generated token

**2. How do I form a REST request which has an array of objects as an input?** I mean perform something like this:

```
?action=createNewVetClinic&vetClinicName=someName&doctors={doctor1: name = "doctor1", occupation="surgeon", salary=100}, {doctor2: name = "doctor2", occupation="dentist", salary=80}
```

Is it possible to create a request like this? I know very noob question, but anyway

Comment: **DO NOT INCLUDE CREDENTIALS IN THE URL PARAMS OF A GET REQUEST**.

Comment: There are two kinds of tokens - access tokens and session tokens. Access tokens should not expire - the user should authenticate and request a token; that token should then be included **as a header at least** with every request. It is a Bad Idea TM to send credentials as URL params. In an ideal world, authentication is by client certificate - that way TLS itself handles authentication. A REST application should be stateless, so session tokens should not be used.

Comment: Further `?action=XXX` Is not REST - It’s “J. Doe’s magic API”. REST would require a URL mapped to a resource and a HTTP verb to carry out an action, for example `GET /token` would create a token and `DELETE /token` would invalidate a token.

Comment: And your final question, it would be `PUT /vet-clinic` with the JSON definition of the clinic in the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **How do I implement authentication/registration and perform actions where auth is required using REST?**

The general consensus for securing REST applications is to send either credentials or access tokens in the HTTP header, rather than in  the request payload, and to include them with every request, as REST is supposed to be a stateless protocol. `Authorization` header is commonly used for that, in the format `Authorization: <Scheme> <Payload>`, where `<Scheme>` is the authorization scheme, and `<Payload>` is usually scheme-dependent. Commonly used authorization schemes include:

- `Basic <base-64-encoded-credentials>`

Payload for this scheme is Base64-encoded credentials in the format `<username>:<password>`. The application should inspect the header, extract the credentials, and validate them against the credential store (your user database or whatnot). The weakness of this method is that the credentials are sent to the server in plain text; mandating HTTPS protocol to access the REST API mitigates this weakness to a great extent, though.

- `Bearer <token>`

Usually used to supply previously generated access tokens. Their advantage is that no credentials need to be sent to the server after an access token has been generated. Again, the application inspects the token, extracts user authorization information from it, and authorizes user based on that. If your application maintains user sessions on the server side, then you can use this scheme to send session tokens; however, this approach is not recommended, as it's not scalable. Rather, various encryption methods can be used to embed user authentication information into the access token itself, so that the token can be decrypted and validated on the server, without the need for a session storage, while still being highly resistant to tampering on the client side. Common such methods include SAML and (my favorite) [JWT](https://jwt.io/). All bearer-using schemes do depend on some sort of an `/generate-access-token` API endpoint.

As for how to intercept and authorize all API requests in a centralized way, I can refer you to one of [my earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799859/how-to-implement-customized-authentication-in-spring-boot-application/47801258#47801258) (it's specific to Spring Boot, but can be easily adapted to plain Spring MVC application as well)